# Show that the triangle $ADC$ is isosceles

Tags: geometry, triangles, circles

Let $K$ be a circle with center $M$ and $L$ be a circle that passes through $M$ and intersects $K$ in two different points $A$ and $B$ and let $g$ be a line that goes through $B$ but not through $A$. Let $C$ be the second point of $g$ on $L$ and let $D$ be the second point of $g$ on $K$ with $C=B$ or $D=B$ if $g$ is the tangent through $B$ on the circle $K$ or $L$. Show that the triangle $ADC$ is isosceles.

For that do we have to show that that the length of each side of triangle is equal? Or how can we show that?

$$$$

**EDIT:**

We get the following, or not?

[image]

Comment: Show that two sides (or two angles) are equal

Comment: But how could we show that? I don't see it how? Could you give me a hint? @MathLover

Comment: Use the fact that $M$ is the center point of arc $AB$ passing through $M$.

Comment: We get the circles as above, or not? @MathLover

Comment: Yes this is one of the constructs. It can also be $D$ between $B$ and $C$.

Comment: Now in your diagram, please note that $AMBC$ is a cyclic quadrilateral.

Comment: We have that angle $A$ is common, as well as side $AC$. We also have that $AD=2\cdot AM$, right? @MathLover

Comment: AMBC is cyclic quadrilateral so $\angle ACB = 180^0  - \angle AMB$ and $\angle AMB$ is two times $\angle ADC$

Comment: But $M$ is not necesarily on the circle $L$, is it? @MathLover

Comment: The question says that circle $L$ goes through point $M$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Let $ \angle  ADC = \alpha$.
What is $ \angle AMB$ in terms of $ \alpha$?
What is $ \angle ACB$ in terms of $ \alpha$?
What is $ \angle DAC$ in terms of $ \alpha$?

Comment: We have that the angle of $ADC$ is an inscribed angle and the angle of $AMB$ is a central angle. That means that $\angle AMB=2\cdot \angle ADC=2\alpha$, right?

Comment: @MaryStar Yes. Keep on going.

Comment: Does it hold that the triangles $ADB$ and $ACB$ are similar and so $\angle ACB=\angle ADB=\alpha$ ?

Comment: @MaryStar Do you think that they are similar? Which angle would $ABD$ (and $ABC$) correspond to in the other triangle?

Comment: I got stuck right now. I don't know how to continue. I though that the triangles $ACB$ and $ADB$ are similar since thet have one side in common and I thoughalso the sides $AD$ and $AC$ are equal, but that is not true. Could you give me a hint what we can say about $\angle ACB$ ?

Comment: @MaryStar A) As I think you're realized, use the fact that $AMCB$ is cyclic. B) Note that edge cases are often better dealt with separately. C) Unfortunately, $AD \neq AC$. It can  be a wrong guess initially, which is why drawing an accurate diagram of a more extreme case is helpful in making guesses at what we should be proving.

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at the two tangent cases also : when $g$ is tangent to $K$ (call it $g_1$) and when $g$ is tangent to $L$ (then call it $g_2$). Both can be shown on same diagram.

[image]

Let $\angle ADB = \alpha$. So $\angle AMB = 2\alpha$ and $\angle ACB=180-2\alpha$.

Now as $g_2$ is tangent to red circle, $\angle ABD = \angle ACB=180-2\alpha$ by alternate segment theorem. Similarly as $g_1$ is tangent to black circle, $\angle ABC= \angle ADB=\alpha$.

The third angles can be calculated. $\angle DAB = \alpha = \angle BAC$.

We have found both $\triangle ABD$ and $\triangle ACB$ are isosceles and similar.

**Note :**

According to question statement, in case of $g_1$, $B=C$ , $\triangle ADB$ in diagram is $\triangle ADC$. While in case of $g_2$, $B=D$, $\triangle ABC$ in diagram is $\triangle ADC$. So we have shown in both cases $\triangle ADC$ (according to question) is isosceles.

Comment: The way I read the question is to prove it in general and special cases being $C = B$ or $D = B$ when they are tangents.

Comment: Ah now I see! I only took those two cases. My bad, I'll edit. Thanks!

Comment: As you said, the way question is worded, there is more time to spend on its interpretation than on its solution :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is another possible construct -

[image]

Please note the proof is very similar. Quadrilateral $AMBC$ is cyclic so

$\angle ACD = 180^0 - \angle AMB$

$\angle ADB = 180^0 - \frac{1}{2} \angle AMB \implies \angle ADC = \frac{1}{2} \angle AMB$

Given $\angle ACD$ and $\angle ADC \,$ in $\triangle ADC, \angle CAD = \frac{1}{2} \angle AMB$.

So $\triangle ADC$ is isosceles.

Comment: Thanks, I misunderstood. +1

Comment: I don't know if I would say you misunderstood. The question is definitely poorly worded!

Comment: Do we get that $AMBC$ is cyclic in each case? I mean no matter how the graph will be, even if $C=B$ or $D=B$ ?

Comment: If $B = C$ then you will have to extend the tangent to intersect with the other circle and say that point is $C' \,$ then $AMBC'$ is cyclic. So you always have a cyclic quadrilateral to work with.